# UWP cant write/read any file

Tags: c#, .net, file, uwp

im trying to write data to file in UWP.

---

Error that crashes: **"Exception thrown:" System.Exception "in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
System.Exception: The APPX file cannot be accessed because it was not encrypted as expected (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070199) "**.

---

I tried to search for the error code on the internet but I found absolutely nothing. When im trying to open created file using notepad it throws the same error.

Here some code

```
public static async void CreateDirectory(string name)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> itemsList = await DirectoriesFolder.GetItemsAsync();
        int newId = itemsList.Count + 1;
        StorageFolder newDir = await DirectoriesFolder.CreateFolderAsync(newId.ToString());
        StorageFile cfgFile = await newDir.CreateFileAsync("DIRECTORYDATADONOTMODIFYORDELETETHISFILE.ddsf");
        
        try
        {
            var buffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary("dupa", Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
            //DirectoryConfigJson(newId, name)
            await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(cfgFile, buffer); // this causes error

        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        ObservableCollection<DirFile> dfList = new ObservableCollection<DirFile>();
    }
```

Comment: I tried the code to write buffer to a local file that I created. The code works on my side. Have you tried to write a different file? What is the `DirectoriesFolder`?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT DirectoriesFolder is StorageFolder where i want to store files. Other files also do not work

Comment: Have you tried the code in a Blank app? Just with the code you posted, I can't reproduce the issue. This behavior might not be related to this part of code.